# How can i control output from crontab?

Tags: command-line, terminal, cron, command-prompt

I am trying to run a test case via automation testing (sahi) , so I am running the command for  it repeatedly after 1 hour (via crontab).
What I want is that is there any solution that **whenever my test case fails i should receive the email otherwise not..** Right now I am reciving mail whether it passes or fails.
In short, can i send mail to a person depending upon the output i get in terminal.
I want to send mail when output will be:
1 scenario (1 failed)
4 steps (3 skipped, 1 failed)
0m2.476s

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you can detect that the test is failing? If command is using the process exit status you could have something like:

```
if ! command ; then
  echo "Error" | mail -s "Error" address@example.com
fi
```

If you want to keep the output:

```
if ! command > results 2>&1 ; then
  cat results | mail -s "Error" address@example.com"
fi
```

Comment: I use sahi for automation testing, it gives output as "failed" or "passed" after running all the cases..I still have to figure out how to pick names of failed cases from the command-line (and then send mail), I think I shoud use grep command or something for this?? ..Thanks.

Comment: If sahi is at all correctly coded, it should also be setting its exit status to indicate success or failure. Look for EXIT STATUS or ERROR CODE or some such in the man page. Then you can simply say `if ! sahi whatever; then ...`